# How to prevent concurrent script runs using LockService?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

If I have a spreadsheet with 15 separate projects, each with a single onEdit() function. The problem I'm having is that occasionally a script will fail to run. I think the issue is concurrency.

The scripts are different but generally look like this:

```js
function onEdit(e){ 
  var edited_range = e.range;

  var edited_row = edited_range.getRow();

  var activeSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet(); 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 

  var source_sheet = ss.getSheetByName("N.Arb Pitches"); 
  var target_sheet = ss.getSheetByName("N.Arb In Progress");
  var last_row = target_sheet.getLastRow(); 

  var range_values = target_sheet.getRange("A1:A").getValues(); 

  var range_length = range_values.filter(String).length + 1;

  var target_range = target_sheet.getRange(range_length,1); 


  if (activeSheet.getName() == "N.Arb Pitches") { 
        if (edited_range.getColumn() == 13) {
          if (edited_range.getValue().toLowerCase() == "yes") {
             target_sheet.insertRowAfter(last_row);  
             source_sheet.getRange(edited_row,1,1,12).copyTo(target_range); 
            source_sheet.deleteRow(edited_row)  }}}; 

}
```

I have been looking into LockService to try to fix this but cannot figure out how it works. I do not understand the documentation or what I am reading online. I have created a new spreadsheet and created two script projects, the first of which holds this code:

```html
function onEdit(e) {

var lock = LockService.getDocumentLock();

try {
    lock.waitLock(10000); 
}
catch (e) {
Browser.msgBox("error");
}
var start = new Date();
var startTime = Number(start.getTime()).toFixed(0);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('N1').setValue('lock1');
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('N2').setValue('success1');


  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('N3').setValue('RELEASED1');
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('N4').setValue(startTime);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    Utilities.sleep(2000);
  lock.releaseLock();    
  
}
```

the second of which holds this code

```html
function onEdit(e) {

var lock = LockService.getDocumentLock();

  
try {
    lock.waitLock(10000); 
}
catch (e) {
Browser.msgBox("error");
}
  var start = new Date();
var startTime = Number(start.getTime()).toFixed(0);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('O1').setValue('lock2');
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('O2').setValue('success2');


    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('O3').setValue('RELEASED2');
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('O4').setValue(startTime);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  Utilities.sleep(2000);
  lock.releaseLock();  

}
```

Like I said I do not understand LockService() but what I think it is implying is that when I subtract the two millisecond times printed out by the scripts, I should see a difference of at least 2,000 but this is NOT what I'm seeing which is actually ~200 in either direction.

What I feel should be happening based on what I understand is that whichever onEdit() script runs first, it will lock the document and prevent any other scripts from running. Then the second script will be stuck in the try() loop until the first releases its lock. Then when the first finishes, it will release the lock and the second script will be free to run, or visa versa if the second script runs first.

That does not make any sense based on what I am seeing actually happen. What is a proper understanding of this code? How can I accomplish what I describe, where no code actually runs concurrently across projects? I would ask more direct questions but tried and my thoughts are jumbled enough I don't know how to form a proper question.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how LockService works, but if your problem is concurrency, you can try adding [`SpreadsheetApp.flush()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush) in between the two functions.

> **flush()**
>
> Applies all pending Spreadsheet changes.
>
> Spreadsheet operations are sometimes bundled together to improve
>   performance, such as when doing multiple calls to Range.getValue().
>   However, sometimes you may want to make sure that all pending changes
>   are made right away, for instance to show users data as a script is
>   executing.

Comment: or in between loops (placed at the end of a loop).. 

So, lately my script went with this error "Error Exception: Service Spreadsheets failed while accessing document with id [spreadhseet id]" which was not happening in the past. I guess it is related to spreadsheet size. When it gets bigger, flush() is neccessary. 

Big thanks to you.